# Read data from hive tables using tensorflow

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow, hive

I want to fetch data from hive tables using Tensorflow. How can i connect hive tables and tensorflow?

Comment: Some searching of Spark + tensorflow should lead you towards an answer

Comment: Or, use any supported library to query Hive, get data in memory, and use Tensorflow like it's any other dataset

Comment: can you please share one code sample @cricket_007

Comment: I cannot. I trust your searching abilities

Comment: In second point you are telling like to read the data using pandas library and store it in memory??

Comment: Assuming you are able to find a Hive connector for Pandas, then yes. Tensorflow isn't mapreduce. It won't run a Hive query itself. Data needs to be locally in memory to be processed. Or use Spark

Answer (score 0):

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext